# What should i do if i want to use functions that are not standard and are due to compiler specific API?

Tags: c++

I have been using the very very old Turbo C++ 3.0 compiler.

During the usage of this compiler, I have become used to functions like `getch()`, `getche()` and most importantly `clrscr()`.

Now I have started using Visual C++ 2010 Express. This is causing a lot of problems, as most of these functions (I found this out now) are non-standard and are not available in Visual C++.

What am I to do now?

Comment: Come back to the year 2013 and learn new technology.

Comment: Depends on what you used that functions for. The easiest answer will be "just don't use them any more".

Comment: Just stop using non-standard API's unless you've a damn-fine reason to do so (and even then, don't).

Comment: Implement them yourself and package it as a library.

Comment: Read more about the native WIN32 [console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: If you absolutely can't get rid of them use conditional compilation depending on which compiler you're.

Comment: You could use _getch (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx) and _getche (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kswce429.aspx), and see here for clearing the screen: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682022%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Always try to avoid them if possible or try their alternatives :

```
for getch() --- cin.get()
clrscr -- system("cls")    // try avoiding the system commands. check : [System][1]
```

And for any others you can search for them .

Comment: sir,

does the behaviour of cin.get() exactly match behavior of getch()?

Comment: getch() takes char and returns it. same with `cin.get()` take char and return. but probably you never assigned it to char variable so you are not sure. try char `x=getch() or char x=cin.get()`

Comment: Sir, i have the old header files also. Is there some way that i can integrate them into Visual C++ 2010?

Comment: there is always a way. but read first line : "avoid them". i never think that i need them.

Comment: well ,actually i just tried it and cin.get() requires the enter key to be pressed. that is exactly what i wanna avoid. is there some way to just take the charachter as it is pressed?

Comment: can i use the function _getch() or _getche()?

Comment: @Arpit `char x = std::cin.get();` is an error.  `std::cin.get()` returns an `int`, because of the out of band value `EOF`.  And although I'm not sure about the semantics of `getch()`, I suspect that it is _not_ the same as those of `std::cin::get()` (and that it cannot be implemented on many platforms).

Comment: @IcyFlame There's no problem including the headers, but it won't help you.  The headers only contain the declaration; you need the definition as well (which is in the compiler specific libraries).

Comment: @Arpit And `system( "cls" )` is not a real solution.  nothing involving `system()` is portable, and if you're willing to use a non-portable solution, I'm sure that there are some system requests in Windows which would do the trick.  (Depending on what the OP is doing with these functions `curses` or `ncurses` might be an appropriate solution.)

Comment: @JamesKanze it is a solution for Visualc++ . System() is a standard function.

Comment: But I used system("cls") with visual c++ and the screen was not cleared!!! What the hell is going on guys? Is there some standard and always works kinda way to clear the screen. And While we are at it, system("pause") is not working!

Comment: @Arpit What does "no error" mean?  If `getch()` has the same
semantics here as it had in earlier MS-DOS, it has distinctly
different semantics that `std::cin::get()`.  And 
`std::cin::get()` returns an `int`---converting it to a `char`
before testing for `EOF` results in a loss of data, and either
you'll never find `EOF`, or you'll find it when it isn't there.
(When a `'ÿ'` is input on many systems in western Europe.)

Comment: Yea. Cin.get()did not work. So I used _getch(). This is really driving me nuts. I guess I will just go back to using turbo c++.

Comment: @Arpit But the string passed to `system` is interpreted in an implementation dependent manner.  `system( "cls" )` doesn't do anything on my Linux box.

Comment: And please tell me if there is any demerit in using turbo c++ now? I have been quite comfortable and I have even written some simple software.  You can see it on my blog: vipersoftware.blogspot.com

Comment: @IcyFlame What system are you on?  `system( "cls" )` and `system( "pause" )` generally work if you're executing in a console window under Windows.  They don't work elsewhere.

Comment: @JamesKanze yes i make the edit for system(). in case of cin.get() it just take a character and convert it to ascii value. if it is assigned to int then ascii value is assigned else a conversion to char will be done. EX: `int x=cin.get()//type 1 and x will be 42 not 1;` `char x=cin.get() //type 1 and you get 1`(Because ascii 42 gets converted)

Comment: I am on a windows xp machine. And I true running this code from visual c++ and from turbo c++. While on turbo it did not work. It is not building properly on visual c++. And is there any solution that is NOT IMPLEMENTATION DEPENDENT?

Comment: @Arpit You must assign the results of `std::cin::get()` to an `int` unless you've taken steps previously (e.g. `std::cin::peek()`) to ensure that it isn't `EOF`.  And `std::cin::get()` will return the character encoding for the character you enter, if you enter a character; it doesn't matter what type you assign it to (except `bool`).  On no machine that I know of will `std::cin::get()` return 1 if you enter a character on the keyboard; if you type a 1 on most systems, it will return 49 (but other values are possible, e.g. 241 on an IBM mainframe).

Comment: @JamesKanze `#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int y=cin.get();
    cout<<y<<endl;
    return 0;
}
`

Comment: @IcyFlame To clear the screen, or to enter a character directly
from the keyboard, without buffering (which I'm assuming is what
`getch` does), no.  To clear the screen, you might try writing
`"\x1b[2J"`; this will work in many console windows (including
xterm and a console window under Windows).  Just be sure to
flush the stream afterwards (and of course, if you write it to
`std::cout`, and `std::cout` has been redirected...).  For
`getch`, the only solution I know would be to get `curses` and
use it.

Comment: @JamesKanze getch() does exactly what you are assuming ;)

Comment: @Arpit And what is that supposed to show (other than, perhaps, that you aren't familiar with iostreams).  If you output an `int`, it is formatted as the integer value.  That's pretty much the definition of `std::ostream`.  What you do with the `int` you get back from `std::istream::get` is up to you.  It's guaranteed to be in the range `[0...UCHAR_MAX]`, or to be `EOF` (which is guaranteed to be negative).  If you convert it to `char` _after_ having checked for `EOF`, there won't be any problems in practice (although formally, it's still implementation defined).

Comment: @Arpit In which case, he needs `curses` or `ncurses` if he wants to be portable.  If he's only concerned about Windows, Joachim Pileborg's comment (which could really be an answer) is probably a good suggestion for a start.  (Joachim didn't explicitly say it wasn't portable, but when you speak about WIN32 console functions, and give a link to Microsoft documentation, I think it's clear enough that it might not work on Unix, not to mention mainframes or other exotics.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24819/discussion-between-arpit-and-james-kanze)

Answer (score 0):

The real question is what you are trying to do, globally.
`getch` and `clrscr` have never been portable.  If you're trying
to create masks or menus in a console window, you should look
into `curses` or `ncurses`: these offer a portable solution for
such things.  If it's just paging, you can probably get away
with simple outputing a large number of `'\n'` (for `clrscr`),
and `std::cin.get()` for `getch`.  (But beware that this will only
return once the user has entered a new line, and will only read
one character of the line, leaving the rest in the buffer.  It
is definitely not a direct replacement for `getch`.  In fact,
`std::getline` or `std::cin::ignore` might be better choices.)

### Edit:

Adding some more possiblities:

First, as Joachim Pileborg suggested in his comment, if
portability is an issue, there may be platform specific
functions for much of what you are trying to do.  If all you're
concerned about is Windows (and it probably is, since `system(
"cls" )` and `getch()` don't work elsewhere), then his comment
may be a sufficient answer.

Second, for many consoles (including xterm and the a console
window under Windows), the escape sequence `"\x1b""2J"` should
clear the screen.  (Note that you have to enter it as two
separate string literals, since otherwise, it would be
interpreted as two characters, the first with the impossible hex
value of 0x1b2.)  Don't forget about possible issues of
redirection and flushing, however.

Finally, if you're doing anything non-trivial, you should look
into `curses` (or `ncurses`, they're the same thing, but with
different implementations).  It's a bit more effort to put into
action (you need explicit initialization, etc.), but it has
a `getch` function which does exactly what you want, and it also
has functions for explicitly positionning the curser, etc. which
may also make your code simpler.  (The original `curses` was
developed to support the original `vi` editor, at UCB.  Any
editor like task not being developed in its own window would
benefit enormously from it.)

Answer (score 0):

Well,

People, i have found the one best solution that can be used everywhere.

I simply googled the definitions of clrscr() and gotoxy() and created a header file and added these definitions to it. Thus, i can include this file and do everything that i was doing prior.

But, i have a query too.

windows.h is there in the definition. suppose i compile the file and make a exe file. Then will i be able to run it on a linux machine?

According to me the answer has to be yes. But please tell me if i am wrong and also tell me why i am wrong.